# to/on a schedule

Tags: meaning

> We’re going to be working **to** a very tight schedule.

http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/tight_1

Can we phrase this sentence as below?

> We’re going to be working **on** a very tight schedule.

Answer (score 4):

The first statement means:

> We’re going to be working **(according) to** a very tight schedule.

Your work is following a schedule.

> We’re going to be working **on** a very tight schedule.

It probably means the same as the first statement, but could also mean that you are formulating/making the tight schedule. More context would help here.

Comment: So the first statement is a simpler way of saying "work according to a tight schedule"?

Comment: Yes, "according" is implied and can be left out without changing the meaning.